# How to get Clean and Build in netbeans to work again?

Tags: 13.10, java, netbeans, jar

I don't know if this is a netbeans or Ubuntu or Java problem. But I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 64bit, and trying to create a jar file from my java application that I've created with Netbeans IDE 7.0.1.

This is what happens when pressing the "Clean and Build" button

```
init:
deps-clean:
Updating property file: /home/jeggy/Skjøl/NetBeansProjects/KTEditor/build/built-clean.properties
Deleting directory /home/jeggy/Skjøl/NetBeansProjects/KTEditor/build
clean:
init:
deps-jar:
Created dir: /home/jeggy/Skjøl/NetBeansProjects/KTEditor/build
Updating property file: /home/jeggy/Skjøl/NetBeansProjects/KTEditor/build/built-jar.properties
Created dir: /home/jeggy/Skjøl/NetBeansProjects/KTEditor/build/classes
Created dir: /home/jeggy/Skjøl/NetBeansProjects/KTEditor/build/empty
Created dir: /home/jeggy/Skjøl/NetBeansProjects/KTEditor/build/generated-sources/ap-source-output
Compiling 11 source files to /home/jeggy/Skjøl/NetBeansProjects/KTEditor/build/classes
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /home/jeggy/Skjøl/NetBeansProjects/KTEditor/src/Connect.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Copying 17 files to /home/jeggy/Skjøl/NetBeansProjects/KTEditor/build/classes
compile:
Created dir: /home/jeggy/Skjøl/NetBeansProjects/KTEditor/dist
Copying 1 file to /home/jeggy/Skjøl/NetBeansProjects/KTEditor/build
/home/jeggy/Skjøl/NetBeansProjects/KTEditor/nbproject/build-impl.xml:990: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/jeggy/Skjøl/NetBeansProjects/KTEditor/nbproject/build-impl.xml:834: copylibs doesn't support the "excludeFromCopy" attribute
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Could someone explain or help me to get this fixed?

Answer (score 0):

It's just a simple Netbeans bug file.
Click on the link on the second to last line which is
`/home/jeggy/Skjøl/NetBeansProjects/KTEditor/nbproject/build-impl.xml:834`:

Remove the attribute of `excludeFromCopy` – not the whole line, only the piece of code associated with it!